# How can one Validate presence of only one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a user model that has_one signup.

I'm having a recurring bug where users will click multiple times and create many unnecessary signups. How can I validate the user only gets one? Is there a way to do that from the model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about your model, but [validates_uniqueness_of](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000086) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In rails 3 you could do like this.

`validates :field, :uniqueness => true`

If you want your custom message then

`validates :field, :uniqueness => {:message => 'your message'}`

Comment: ah i didn't know that. I ended up doing validates_uniques_of :user_id which philosophically accomplishes what i wanted perfectly